# Let $f:\Bbb{N}\to\Bbb{C}$ denotes the indicator function of squares. Express it in terms of Mobious function $\mu$.

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions, multiplicative-function, dirichlet-convolution

Here $f(n)=\begin{cases}
1\ \text{if } n=m^2\text{ for some }m\in\Bbb{N}\\
0\ \text{if otherwise} 
\end{cases}$

This is a multiplicative function. At first I define $g:\Bbb{N}\to\Bbb{C}$ be $g(n)$ to be number of square divisors of $n$.

Then it's easy to verify that $\mu\ast g=f$.

But later I realised that $g$ is nothing but $g= \mathbb{1}\ast f$ where $1$ denotes the constant function $1$. Then $\mu*g=(\mu*1)*f=\delta*f=f$ where $\delta(1)=1$ and $\delta(n)=0\ \forall n>1$.

So my solution i.e. the expression of $f$ is not giving anything special.

Can anyone help me in this regard? Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: What's $*$ here?

Comment: @aschepler In this context, I would assume it is the [Dirichlet convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution).

Comment: I note that $\sum_{d \mid n} 1+\mu(d)$ is almost what you want.  It's odd on the squares bigger than $1$ and even otherwise.

Comment: @aschepler $*$ is Dirichlet convolution

Comment: @EricTowers Remove the $\mu(d)$ term, and you are even closer, as that also puts 1 together with the other squares.

Comment: @Arthur I don't understand your comment, could you please just write from where you are removing

Comment: @Arthur : No.  All terms are $\mu(d)$ terms.

Comment: @EricTowers My point is, if we set $k(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}( 1+\mu( d))$ to be your function, and $\ell(n)=\sum_{d\mid n} 1$, then $$\frac{1-(-1)^{k(n)}}2$$ has the correct value everywhere except at $n=1$. On the other hand, $$\frac{1-(-1)^{\ell(n)}}{2}$$ is exactly the function OP is looking for, although that's probably not the expression they are asked to find.

Comment: @Arthur : $\ell$ fails to meet the requirement "in terms of the Moebius function".

Comment: @EricTowers And yours fails to meet the value requirements _precisely because_ you shoehorned in the Moebius function. So I wouldn't call it "almost what you want".

Comment: @Arthur : I'm perfectly happy using the indicator function at $1$, $\sum_{d \mid n} \mu(d)$ to correct at $1$, since that is also in terms of $\mu$.  But I'm not here to do anyone's homework, so I was leaving that to the OP.

Comment: So you're saying that $\sum_{d\mid n}(1+\mu(d))-\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)$ is what we're after? I mean, technically that fulfills the requirements (as an exponent to $-1$), but I sincerely doubt that that's what the problem author was after.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your question is, but whether or not the expression $f=g\star 1$ is useful remains to be seen.  We have
\[ \sum _{n\leq x}f(n)=\sum _{d\leq x}g(d)\sum _{n\leq x\atop {d|n}}1=x\sum _{d\leq x}\frac {g(d)}{d}+\mathcal O\left (\sum _{d\leq x}|g(d)|\right ).\]
If $g$ is weighted differently to $f$, this expression may be useful.  If $g$ is weighted only on squares for example (where $f$ may not be), then the sum in the error is
\[ \sum _{d^2\leq x}1=\sum _{d\leq \sqrt x}1\]
so
\[ \sum _{n\leq x}f(n)=x\sum _{d\leq x}\frac {g(d)}{d}+\mathcal O\left (\sqrt x\right ).\]
Of course, the main term will simplify for the same reason, but the point I want to make is that the error term is small because the sum was *of shorter length*.  Re-writing functions as certain convolutions so that the sums arising have different lengths has proven to be one of the most fruitful ideas in analytic number theory.

So you are right to notice that your convolution is nothing special, as long as sum length is nothing is special.  But it is!

(And if you want a concrete example, then take $f$ to be the indicator of the squarefree numbers.  Then you can find $g$ by the argument you make in your post.  Now my argument above will give you the same error term and a main term
\[ x\sum _{d\leq x}\frac {\mu (d)}{d^2}=x\sum _{d=1}^\infty \frac {\mu (d)}{d^2}+\mathcal O(1)=\frac {x}{\zeta (2)}+\mathcal O(1),\]
so you've counted the squarefree numbers up to $x$.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you're looking for but it is interesting (and easy) to note that in your notation;

$f=\lambda*1 = \sum_{d \mid n} \lambda(d)$

where $\lambda$ is the [Liouville function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_function)